# Animated.View snaps back to original position instead of a slower transition

Tags: react-native

Here is the Snack demo: `https://snack.expo.dev/@spk265/playful-ice-cream`. As can be seen, the transition from L->R is smooth but R->L is not. How can I make the transition smooth in both directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the animated value in a useRef so that it does not get recreated all the time

Example: https://snack.expo.dev/eZ4bmqavH

Comment: That works, thank you @nios ! Could you please explain why using `useRef` works here?

Comment: useRef makes sure the value/object is the same in the entire lifetime of the component. Since it is an instance of a class it would be recreated on re-render causing you the issues you where having.